# Localised name of the app is incorrect iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I have an iOS app which is localised in German and English. Below is the contents of infoPlist.strings(english as well as German) files.

```
/* Localized versions of Info.plist German keys */
CFBundleDisplayName = "ABCinGerman";
CFBundleName = "ABCinGerman";

/* Localized versions of Info.plist English keys */
CFBundleDisplayName = "ABCinEnglish";
CFBundleName = "ABCinEnglish";
```

If the device language is set to German, I can see appname being displayed on the iphone as ABCinGerman.

if the device language is set to English, I can see appname as target_name not ABCinEnglish. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Give this app a try. I've never used it, but I saw a blog post about it. The post made it seem like the Mac App did everything for you.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/localize-apps-now/id963897797?mt=12

Comment: This app have totally different purpose. Description
Localize Apps Now localizes your iOS or OSX apps straight out of the box. 

Just drag your .strings file into the app and it will translate the strings into over 50 languages and save them out in the correct folder structure for Xcode to recognise. 

Had hassle with getting your app translated in time for a release? 
This app will translate your app in seconds, no more waiting around for companies to respond to emails or send you translations that are late!